# mac bash version 3.2.57→ bash 4.4.12 バージョンアップについて。

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

Mac OS 10.11.16
初心者なのですがネットの情報を見ながら、bashのバージョンアップをしました。Homebrewをインストールすると楽にバージョンアップができそうだったので、インストールしてすべて完了しました。
現在、下記のような状態なのですが、バージョンアップはうまくいっているのでしょうか。

`bash --version`　で確認すると version 3.2.57のままです。

```
fJ$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

しかし `set | less` で確認すると

```
BASH=/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.4.12/bin/bash
BASH_VERSION='4.4.12(1)-release'
SHELL=/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.4.12/bin/bash
```

これはバージョンアップはできているのでしょうか？それともversion 3.2.57のままでしょうか。
ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元に環境がないので、半分推測ですが。。

- `BASH_VERSION` を見る限り、今実行しているシェルは、 4.4.12 になっている
- `PATH` から最初に読み込まれる bash は、 3.2.57 になっている

なので:

- 端末が最初に呼ぶシェルは 4.4.12
  (端末の設定から、読み込むシェルを指定できたはず)
- 4.4.12 は、しかし PATH からは呼べないところにある or 3.2.57 (おそらく mac に元から入っている bash) より後に読み込む設定になっている。

いくつか考えつく回避方法:

- `.bash_profile` にて、 `PATH="${BASH%/*}:$PATH"` のように記述し、今動いている　BASH の bin ディレクトリを PATH の最初に持ってくる
- `.bashrc` にて、 `alias bash=$BASH` を行い、 bash を今現在の BASH 変数でもっておきかえる。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます！！私ではまだ理解できないのですが、.bash_profileにPATH="${BASH%/*}:$PATH"と記述することで解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @user25524 お役に立てたようで何よりです。 `${variable%workd}` の記法は、シェルの変数展開の方法の一つで、例えば次サイトなどが参考になります。 http://dharry.hatenablog.com/entry/20090211/1234290856

また、この回答で問題が解決した場合には、[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) をお願いできますでしょうか？システム的に、問題が解決済みであることを示すことができます。